# Почему при сборке моего проекта на Vue.js с помощью Gulp и Browserify на страницу ничего не отрисовывается?

Tags: vue.js, gulp

Я пытаюсь собрать проект на Vue.js с помощью Gulp и Browserify, но на страницу ничего не отрисовывается. С чем это может быть связано?

Задача в gulpfile.js:

```js
gulp.task('js', function() {
  return browserify({ entries: './src/main.js'})
    .transform(babelify, { presets: ['es2015'] })
    .transform(vueify)
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('build.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});
```

main.js:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar.vue'
import MenuItem from './components/MenuItem.vue'
import Vue2Scrollbar from './components/Vue2Scrollbar.vue'
import Submenu from './components/Submenu.vue'

Vue.component('app-sidebar', Sidebar);
Vue.component('app-menu-item', MenuItem);
Vue.component('app-scrollbar', Vue2Scrollbar);
Vue.component('app-submenu', Submenu);

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    render: h => h(App.default)
})
```

DOM-дерево после запуска сервера:
[image: DOM-дерево после запуска сервера]

Comment: Зачем вы используете для таких целей Gulp? У вью уже сделан и настроен отлично вебпак, зачем что-то своё городить, что не будет нормально работать

Comment: Задание мне такое дали: настроить сборку проекта на Vue.js с помощью Gulp

Comment: @Станислав, так обоснуйте, что это бессмысленно и беспощадно! Технологии стоит использовать так как их задумывали разработчики, а не искать извращения в их реализации! Для использования vue есть vue-cli

Comment: Спасибо! Если не найду ответа на свой вопрос, скажу работодателю, что лучше настраивать сборку с помощью Vue-cli и собирать проект с помощью Webpack.